# httpPost android php

Tags: php, android

i am sending a username from android client to a php server , but it seems that POST doesn't work and the username is not read by the server ...

android code

```
package com.example.election;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.ResponseHandler;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.BasicResponseHandler;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.protocol.BasicHttpContext;
import org.apache.http.protocol.HttpContext;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class authentification extends Activity {

    Button Quitter, Annuler, Valider;
    EditText login,password;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.authentification);
        Quitter = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Quitter);
        Valider = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Valider);
        Annuler = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Annuler);
        login = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.login);

        password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);


        Valider.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                verifier_admin(v);

            }
        });


        Quitter.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                        MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);

            }
        });

    }


    public void reset(View v){
        login = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.login);
        password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
        login.setText("");
        password.setText("");

    }

    public void verifier_admin(View v){
        InputStream is = null;
        HttpClient httpclient = null;
        HttpPost httppost = null;
        HttpResponse response = null;
        HttpEntity entity = null;

        ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = null; 
        String pass;
        String log = login.getText().toString();

        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost post = new HttpPost("http://172.16.50.239:80/android/test.php");
        HttpContext localContext = new BasicHttpContext();

        pass =password.getText().toString();

        if(log.length()>0 ){

            try{
                List<NameValuePair> var = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);  

                var.add(new BasicNameValuePair("log",log));

                //var.add(new  BasicNameValuePair("pass",pass));
               // post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity (var,"utf-8"));
                post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity (var));
                ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler=new BasicResponseHandler();
                String reponse =client.execute(post,responseHandler);

                //BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));
                //String s = reader.readLine();
                Toast.makeText(this, "message envoyé",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                login.setText("");


            }
            catch(ClientProtocolException e )
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            catch(IOException e )
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

        else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "veuillez entrez vos données",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
}
}
```

php code

```
<?php
if( isset($_POST)  ){
print_r($_POST);




//connexion base
$link = mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die ('ERREUR '.mysql_error()) ;
$bd_selected=mysql_select_db("mydb",$link) or die ('ERREUR1 '.mysql_error());

$req1=" SELECT * FROM user WHERE (login= '$log')";

$sql=mysql_query($req); 
$data = mysql_num_rows($sql);// affiche le nombre de ligne satisfaisant condition
echo $req;



mysql_close($link);
}
?>
```

the error is that the $log=$_POST['log'] undefined

Comment: try $_REQUEST instead of post

Comment: it doen't work , same result

Comment: is ur api on remote or local?

Comment: check ur api with get first on browser and then u can post it

Comment: `Houssem Marzougi alias As Sima alias Ghada Ben Tekfa` `the error is that the $log=$_POST['log'] undefined `  You should not use your browser to test your android client. And do not register every day under a new name while deleting your former posts. You have been answered already about not using your browser to begin with. And again you come here to claim other peoples time. You have not learned anything from your earlier posts and our explanations.

Comment: SELECT * FROM user WHERE (login= '$log')"; , here where is @log intialized??

Comment: log is posted from a client android to php

Comment: yes but u hv to get from post to variable,  $log=$_POST['log'] where is this line?

Comment: i made it now but the same error : Notice: Undefined index: log in C:\xampp\htdocs\android\connection.php on line 6

Answer (score 0):

Try This Code
you just left one single line in your code rest everything is fine

```
    <?php    
    $log=$_POST['log'];   // Here define log value in $log variable
    if( isset($_POST)  )
    {
    print_r($_POST);

//connexion base

    $link = mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die ('ERREUR '.mysql_error()) ;
    $bd_selected=mysql_select_db("mydb",$link) or die ('ERREUR1 '.mysql_error());

    $req1=" SELECT * FROM user WHERE (login= '$log')";

    $sql=mysql_query($req1); 
    $data = mysql_num_rows($sql);// affiche le nombre de ligne satisfaisant condition
    echo $req1;    
    mysql_close($link);
    }
    ?>
```